# how to add page break using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, how to add page break, my page cut if convert to pdf ..??

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("content")).then(function (canvas) {
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: "landscape",
    format: "a4",
  });
  doc.addImage(img, "JPEG", 1, 5);
  doc.save("testCanvas.pdf");
});
```

Comment: you can use css `page-brake-*`

Comment: is this an angular or jQuery app. If you are using Angular it's not good practice to use jQuery. html2canvas works on angular without using jquery

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For PDF conversion, use this library instead, it supports break pages :

https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf