# jsPDF break paragraph at the end of page in React js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, jspdf

Hello I have a lot of HTML data with lot of paragraphs with `<p>` tag stored in variable `let element`.  I am creating a PDF document via jsPDF library in React. The document is being created successfully with 5 pages, however a line break is created inside of last paragraph of the first page and so on with other pages. So how can I manage page height and add more pages in my pdf document. My code is as following:

```
    let element = (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "left", width:"600px"}}>
             <p style={{fontSize: "10px", color:"#000"}}>
                text text....................
             </p>
            <p style={{fontSize: "10px", color:"#000"}}>
                text text.........................
             </p>
      </div>
   );


  const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
    doc.html(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element), {
    callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save('AgreementLetter.pdf');
    }
  });
```

My Issue result is like this
[image]

Please help with this, thanks.

Comment: @k-j which line you are saying? there are many pages and many paragraph embedding in PDF document.

Comment: Maybe this could help for your needs: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943678/how-to-add-page-break-using-jspdf-and-html2canvas#:~:text=For%20PDF%20conversion%2C%20use%20this%20library%20instead%2C%20it%20supports%20break%20pages%20%3A

Answer (score 0):

To set top and bottom margin and auto paging resolved the issue.

```
 const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "legal");
   doc.html(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element), {
   callback: function (doc) {

    doc.save('Letter.pdf');
  },
    margin: [10, 20, 30, 10],
    autoPaging: 'text',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 655, 
    windowWidth: 675
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this its working me:-

```
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
var base = doc.html(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element), {
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.17,
    },
    margin: [20, 5, 20, 5],
    autoPaging: 'text',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 655, 
    windowWidth: 675,
    callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('download.pdf');
    },
});

/** Convert PDF into base64 */
const base64PDF = await base.output('datauristring')
```

if you dont need page size, you use below like

```
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [612, 1200]);
```

refence from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233354/losing-content-when-i-convert-html-to-pdf-with-jspdf?rq=3)